# REST API / OpenBanking API - Location Resource Aggregation URL

Tags: rest, open-banking

What would be best practise to aggregate the below resources as a single API call, *(the reason is to avoid making multiple calls to get all the resources from mobile/IoT)*

/branches

/atms

/itms

I can think of aggregating them under a parent like /locations, so it would be something like below,

/locations -> aggregator

/locations/branches

/locations/atms

/locations/itms

The question is, is the above a good practice considering that this has to be compliant with openBanking API specification, or any other solutions/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`openBanking API` specification is not considering for your problem and it is created to publish banking services as tangible APIs to third-party organizations like `finTechs`.

The solution to aggregate resources and APIs for multiple channels is **API Gateway**. you could consider some frameworks like `Zuul` or `IBM Data Power`.